# Finding the equation for a parabola given two points and the vertex on a line.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, polynomials

Find the equations for the parabolas $y = a(x-h)^2+k$ that go through the points $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$.  The vertex is on the line $y = mx + b$.

I am working with hard values for the points and the line the vertex falls on.  I am looking for a strategy to solve this kind of problem.  Evidently there are two solutions, so I suspect the solution involves solving a quadratic equation.

The following page describes how to find parabolas through two points.
https://www.illustrativemathematics.org/content-standards/tasks/379

Sample problem.

Find the equations for the parabolas that go through the points $(2,5)$ and $(6,53)$.  The vertex is on the line $y = 2x + 1$.

I have posted my attempt as an answer.

Comment: To get started, try substituting in both $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$ and solving the simultaneous equations to get a general parabola that passes through both points.

Comment: hint: coordinates of vertex will be $(h, mh+b)$

Comment: Re: Kelly, If I am not mistaken, subtracting the equations gives something like $a(x_1^2-x_0^2-2h(x_1-x_0)))-((y_1-y_0)=0$.  This appears to be a hyperbola with the variables being $a$ and $h$.  I am not sure how to use it in conjunction with $y=mx+b$ to pin down the third points to define the equations for the parabola.

Comment: Re: Vasya, I think my conceptual gap is using $y=mx+b$ to pin down the third points that define the equations for the parabolas.  I need to solve for $a$, $h$ and $k$ given $(x_0,y_0)$, $(x_1,y_1)$, $m$ and $b$.  Getting from there to $(h, k=mh+b)$ is where I seem to have a conceptual gap.

Comment: Solving for $a$ and subtracting to eliminate it gives $\frac{y_0-k}{(x_0-h)^2} = \frac{y_1-k}{(x_1-h)^2}$.  Evidently $$h=\frac{2 (x_0 (k-y_1) + x_1 (y_0 - k)) \pm \sqrt{(-2 (x_0 (k-y_1) + x_1 (k-y_0))^2 - 4(y_0-y_1)(x_0^2(k-y_1)+x_1^2(y_0-k))}}{2(y_0-y_1)}$$ and $$k=\frac{h^2(y_1-y_0)+2h(x_1y_0-x_0y_1)+x_0^2y_1-x_1^2y_0}{(x_0-x_1)(-2h+x_0+x_1)}$$ Assuming $x = h$ and $y = k$ on the vertex, $$mh+b=\frac{h^2(y_1-y_0)+2h(x_1y_0-x_0y_1)+x_0^2y_1-x_1^2y_0}{(x_0-x_1)(-2h+x_0+x_1)}$$ Is this the most straightforward way to solve this kind of problem?  I am not convinced that it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to attack a problem like this is to try to transform it into something that is simpler to solve.
For this problem, we might want to try using different coordinate axes.

Rotating the horizontal axis would change how we identify the vertex of the parabola because the minimum or maximum "vertical" value would occur at a different point. Rotating the vertical axis would cause the parabola no longer to be the graph of a function. So let's keep the axes in the same orientation as the given $x$ and $y$ axes. But we can put the origin anywhere we want and scale either axis by any amount independently (possibly even reversing the positive direction) without changing how we identify the vertex.

The problem is relatively easy when the $y$-coordinates of both points are the same, because then $h = \frac{x_1 + x_2}2.$
So let's consider only the case in which $y_1 \neq y_2,$
and suppose we choose coordinate axes labeled $X$ and $Y$ such that the two points the parabola must pass through have $(X,Y)$ coordinates 
$(-1,-1)$ and $(1,1).$
We can do this by setting
\begin{align}
X &= \frac{2}{x_2 - x_1}\left(x - \frac{x_1 + x_2}{2}\right), \tag1\\
Y &= \frac{2}{y_2 - y_1}\left(y - \frac{y_1 + y_2}{2}\right). \tag2
\end{align}

Then 
\begin{align}
x &= \left(\frac{x_2 - x_1}{2}\right)X + \frac{x_1 + x_2}{2}, \\
y &= \left(\frac{y_2 - y_1}{2}\right)Y + \frac{y_1 + y_2}{2},
\end{align}
and the equation of the line $y = mx + b$ can be rewritten as
$$
\left(\frac{y_2 - y_1}{2}\right)Y + \frac{y_1 + y_2}{2}
= m\left(\frac{x_2 - x_1}{2}\right)X + m\left(\frac{x_1 + x_2}{2}\right) + b,
$$
that is, $Y = MX + B,$ where
\begin{align}
M &= \frac{mx_2 - mx_1}{y_2 - y_1}, \tag3\\
B &= \frac{mx_1 + mx_2 - y_1 - y_2 + 2b}{y_2 - y_1}. \tag4
\end{align}

Let the equation of the parabola in these coordinates be
$$Y = A(X - H)^2 + K. \tag5$$
Since the parabola passes through the points
$(X,Y) = (-1,-1)$ and $(X,Y) = (1,1),$
we know that
\begin{align}
-1 &= A(-1 - H)^2 + K = A(1 - 2H + H^2) + K, \\
 1 &= A(1 - H)^2 + K = A(1 + 2H + H^2) + K, \\
-1 - 1 &= (A(1 + 2H + H^2) + K) - (A(1 - 2H + H^2) + K),\\
-2 &= 4AH,
\end{align}
from which we find that
$$
A = -\frac{1}{2H}. \tag6
$$
Solving for $K$ in Equation $(5),$
$$ K = 1 - A(1 - H)^2 = 1 + \frac{(1 - H)^2}{2H} 
= \frac12\left(H + \frac1H\right). \tag7
$$

Therefore the vertex of the parabola has coordinates
$\left(H, \frac12\left(H + \frac1H\right)\right).$
In order for that point to lie on the line
$Y = MX + B,$ we require that

\begin{align}
\frac12\left(H + \frac1H\right) &= MH + B, \\
0 &= \left(M - \frac12\right) H + B - \frac1{2H} , \\
0 &= \left(M - \frac12\right) H^2 + BH - \frac12 .
\end{align}

In the case where $M = \frac12,$ this equation implies that 
$H = -\frac{1}{2B}.$
This will lead to exactly one solution if $B\neq 0$;
the problem has no solution if $M = \frac12$ and $B = 0.$
But if $M \neq \frac12$ we have a quadratic equation in $H,$
whose solution (if it exists) is
$$
H = \frac{-B \pm \sqrt{B^2 + 2M - 1}}{2M - 1}. \tag8
$$
Note that if $M < \frac12$ there is a solution only if 
$\lvert B\rvert \geq \sqrt{1 - 2M},$
and there is only one solution when $M < \frac12$
and $\lvert B\rvert = \sqrt{1 - 2M}$;
otherwise there are two solutions.

Now to apply this to the general problem, given the coordinates
$(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ and the equation of the line $y = mx + b,$
we can take Equation $(5)$ 
and use Equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ to substitute for $X$ and $Y,$ obtaining
$$
\frac{2}{y_2 - y_1}\left(y - \frac{y_1 + y_2}{2}\right)
 = A\left(\frac{2}{x_2 - x_1}
          \left(x - \frac{x_1 + x_2}{2}\right) - H\right)^2 + K.
$$

Redistributing some factors, we get
$$
\frac{2}{y_2 - y_1}\left(y - \frac{y_1 + y_2}{2}\right)
 = \frac{4A}{(x_2 - x_1)^2}
    \left(x - \frac{x_1 + x_2}{2} - \frac{x_2 - x_1}{2}H\right)^2 + K
$$
and then
$$
y - \frac{y_1 + y_2}{2}
 = \frac{2A(y_2 - y_1)}{(x_2 - x_1)^2}
     \left(x - \frac{x_1 + x_2}{2} - \frac{x_2 - x_1}{2}H\right)^2 
   + \frac{K(y_2 - y_1)}{2}
$$
and finally, by adding a constant to both sides,
$$
y = \frac{2A(y_2 - y_1)}{(x_2 - x_1)^2}
     \left(x - \frac{x_1 + x_2}{2} - \frac{x_2 - x_1}{2}H\right)^2 
   + \frac{K(y_2 - y_1) + y_1 + y_2}{2}. \tag9
$$

At this point you should be able to recognize which of these expressions
is $a,$ $h,$ and $k$ in the desired equation $y = a(x - h)^2 + k.$

To write this completely in terms of the variables $x$ and $y$
and the parameters $x_1,$ $y_1,$ $x_2,$ $y_2,$ $m,$ and $b$ given in the problem statement,
you could use Equations $(6)$ and $(7)$ to substitute for $A$ and $K,$
then use Equation $(8)$ to substitute for $H,$
and finally use Equations $(3)$ and $(4)$ to substitute for $M$ and $B.$
I would not recommend writing this result out in full detail, however;
it seems more practical to me to say the equation of the parabola is
Equation $(9)$ where $A,$ $H,$ and $K$ are defined by the equations above.
This enables plugging in actual numeric values to work examples.

In fact, I would even recommend introducing some additional symbols in
order to make Equation $(9)$ easier to work with:
\begin{align}
\bar x &= \frac{x_1 + x_2}{2}, & \delta_x &= \frac{x_2 - x_1}{2},\\
\bar y &= \frac{y_1 + y_2}{2}, & \delta_y &= \frac{y_2 - y_1}{2}.
\end{align}
Then Equation $(9)$ becomes
$$
y = \frac{A\delta_y}{\delta_x^2}\left(x - \bar x - H\delta_x\right)^2 
      + K\delta_y + \bar y. 
$$

Comment: Thank you much.  I will work through this as time permits.

Comment: $\frac{2}{x_2-x_1}$ scales the axis so the distance between $x_1$ and $x_2$ is exactly 2. $-\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}$ is an offset that centers the axis between $x_1$ and $x_2$.  That makes sense.  Geometrically, what does $M=\frac{1}{2}$ imply?  What is the implication when $B=0$ and $M=\frac{1}{2}$?  What do the additional terms you introduced represent conceptually?

Comment: The terms $\bar x, \delta_x, \bar y,$ and $\delta_y$ are just the offsets and scaling factors (or their reciprocals) that scale and shift the points $(x_1,y_2)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ to $(-1,-1)$ and $(1,1).$ The capital letters correspond to the lower-case letters but in the transformed coordinates instead of the original coordinates. The graph of $K=\frac12(H+(1/H))$ has two branches, which are asymptotic to the $Y$ axis (halfway between the two point) and to the line $Y = \frac12X$--that is, the line with slope $M=\frac12$ in transformed coordinates.

Comment: Are the asymptotic properties of $K=\frac{1}{2}(H+\frac{1}{H})$ an artifact of the scaling or a property of the original problem?

Comment: The graph is a hyperbola. When you transform back to the original coordinates, it's still a hyperbola with one vertical asymptote and one sloped asymptote, but the intersection point of the asymptotes will be $(\bar x,\bar y)$ instead of $(0,0)$ and the slope of the sloped asymptote will be $\frac12\delta_y/\delta_x$ instead of $\frac12.$

Comment: It seems like one solution is excluded when $1=B^2+2M$ and another solution is excluded when $M=\frac{1}{2}$.  In either case it is impossible to hit both branches of the hyperbola.  This leads to no solutions when $B=0$ and $M=\frac{1}{2}$.  If $B^2+2M<1$ there also are no solutions.  Otherwise there are two solutions.  Basically, no solutions are possible when the vertex line passes between the two fixed points such that a parabola is geometrically impossible.

Comment: @user550795 That's a good summary of the possibilities for solutions.

Comment: $y=Mx+B$ is tangent to $y = \frac{1}{2}(x+\frac{1}{x})$, so only one solution is possible.  When $M=\frac{1}{2}$ or the line takes the form $x=B$, the line can only intersect with one branch of the hyperbola because it is parallel to an asymptote.  When $\frac{1}{2}<M$, the line intersects both branches.  When $M<\frac{1}{2}$ and $1<B^2+2M$, the line intersects the same branch of the hyperbola twice.  No intersection is possible when the line passes between the points, or $B^2+2M<1$.  No intersection is possible if the line is one of the asymptotes, either $y= Mx= \frac{1}{2}x$ or $x = B = 0$.

Comment: The other thing to note is that an intersection with the positive branch of the hyperbola corresponds to a parabola that opens down $Y_2<Y_1=1\le Y_{vertex}$, and an intersection with the negative branch to a parabola that open up $Y_{vertex}\le -1=Y_2<Y_1$. This is, however, in the transformed space. If the scaling flipped the y-axis, the final parabolas will face the other direction. It is also obviously possible to tell whether or not the vertex falls between the fixed points, on one of them, or to one side. Different combinations correspond to the different kinds of solutions listed above.

Comment: What is the derivation of equations (1) and (2)?  These kinds of transformations look like they could be useful in other practical contexts.

Comment: First do a translation of coordinates so that the midpoint of $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ is mapped to $(0,0).$ Then scale each axis so that $x_1$ and $x_2$ map to $-1$ and $1$ and so that $y_1$ and $y_2$ map to $-1$ and $1.$ Parabolas map to parabolas, the vertex of the old parabola maps to the new one's vertex, hyperbolas map to hyperbolas, and ellipses map to ellipses (if you consider a circle a special type of ellipse).

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt to answer my own question.

Substituting for $x$ and $y$, subtracting equations and solving for $a$ gives the following.
$$
y_1 - y_0=(a(x_1-h)^2+k) - (a(x_0-h)^2+k) \\
(y_1 - y_0)=a((x_1-h)^2 - (x_0-h)^2) \\
a = \frac{y_1 - y_0}{(x_1-h)^2 - (x_0-h)^2}
$$

Substituting for $x$, $y$ and $a$, adding equations and solving for $k$ gives the following.
$$
y_1 + y_0=(a(x_1-h)^2+k) + (a(x_0-h)^2+k) \\
(y_1 + y_0)=a((x_1-h)^2 + (x_0-h)^2) + 2k \\
(y_1 + y_0)=\frac{y_1 - y_0}{(x_1-h)^2 - (x_0-h)^2}((x_1-h)^2 + (x_0-h)^2) + 2k \\
2k = (y_1 + y_0) - \frac{(y_1 - y_0)((x_1-h)^2 + (x_0-h)^2)}{(x_1-h)^2 - (x_0-h)^2} \\
2k = \frac{(y_1 + y_0)((x_1-h)^2 - (x_0-h)^2) - (y_1 - y_0)((x_1-h)^2 + (x_0-h)^2)}{(x_1-h)^2 - (x_0-h)^2} \\
2k = \frac{(y_0(x_1-h)^2+y_1(x_1-h)^2-y_0(x_0-h)^2-y_1(x_0-h)^2) - (-y_0(x_1-h)^2+y_1(x_1-h)^2-y_0(x_0-h)^2+y_1(x_0-h)^2)}{(x_1-h)^2 - (x_0-h)^2} \\
2k = \frac{(y_0(x_1-h)^2+y_1(x_1-h)^2-y_0(x_0-h)^2-y_1(x_0-h)^2) + (y_0(x_1-h)^2-y_1(x_1-h)^2+y_0(x_0-h)^2-y_1(x_0-h)^2)}{(x_1-h)^2 - (x_0-h)^2} \\
2k = \frac{y_0(x_1-h)^2+y_0(x_1-h)^2+y_1(x_1-h)^2-y_1(x_1-h)^2-y_0(x_0-h)^2+y_0(x_0-h)^2-y_1(x_0-h)^2-y_1(x_0-h)^2}{(x_1-h)^2 - (x_0-h)^2} \\
2k = \frac{2(y_0(x_1-h)^2 - y_1(x_0-h)^2)}{(x_1-h)^2 - (x_0-h)^2} \\
k = \frac{y_0(x_1-h)^2 - y_1(x_0-h)^2}{(x_1-h)^2 - (x_0-h)^2} \\
$$

Substituting for $a$ and $k$ in the original equation gives a parabola in terms of $h$ that goes through the points $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$.

$$
y = a(x-h)^2+k \\
y = \frac{y_1 - y_0}{(x_1-h)^2 - (x_0-h)^2}(x-h)^2 + \frac{y_0(x_1-h)^2 - y_1(x_0-h)^2}{(x_1-h)^2 - (x_0-h)^2} \\
y = \frac{(y_1 - y_0)(x-h)^2 + y_0(x_1-h)^2 - y_1(x_0-h)^2}{(x_1-h)^2 - (x_0-h)^2} \\
y = \frac{(y_1 - y_0)(x-h)^2 + y_0(x_1-h)^2 - y_1(x_0-h)^2}{(x_1^2-2x_1h+h^2) - (x_0^2-2x_0h+h^2)} \\
y = \frac{(y_1 - y_0)(x-h)^2 + y_0(x_1-h)^2 - y_1(x_0-h)^2}{x_1^2-x_0^2-2x_1h+2x_0h} \\
y = \frac{(y_1 - y_0)(x-h)^2 + y_0(x_1-h)^2 - y_1(x_0-h)^2}{(x_1-x_0)(x_0+x_1)-2h(x_1-x_0)} \\
y = \frac{(y_1 - y_0)(x-h)^2 + y_0(x_1-h)^2 - y_1(x_0-h)^2}{(x_1-x_0)(x_0+x_1-2h)} \\
y = \frac{(y_1 - y_0)(x-h)^2 + y_0(x_1-h)^2 - y_1(x_0-h)^2}{(x_0-x_1)(2h-x_0-x_1)}
$$

The above is clearly useless when $x_0=x_1$ or $y_0=y_1$.  In any case, the vertex is located at $(h,mh+b)$.  Substituting for $x$, $y$ and solving for $h$ gives the following.

$$
y = a(x-h)^2+k \\
mh+b = a(h-h)^2+k \\
mh+b = k \\
h = \frac{k}{m} - \frac{b}{m} \\
h = \frac{y_0(x_1-h)^2 - y_1(x_0-h)^2}{m((x_1-h)^2 - (x_0-h)^2)} - \frac{b}{m} \\
h = \frac{y_0(x_1-h)^2 - y_1(x_0-h)^2 - b((x_1-h)^2 - (x_0-h)^2)}{m((x_1-h)^2 - (x_0-h)^2)} \\
hm((x_1-h)^2 - (x_0-h)^2) = y_0(x_1-h)^2 - y_1(x_0-h)^2 - b((x_1-h)^2 - (x_0-h)^2) \\
hm((x_1-h)^2 - (x_0-h)^2) + b((x_1-h)^2 - (x_0-h)^2) = y_0(x_1-h)^2 - y_1(x_0-h)^2 \\
(hm + b)((x_1-h)^2 - (x_0-h)^2) = y_0(x_1-h)^2 - y_1(x_0-h)^2 \\
0 = (hm + b)((x_1-h)^2 - (x_0-h)^2) + y_1(x_0-h)^2 - y_0(x_1-h)^2 \\
0 = 2 h^2 m x_0 - 2 h^2 m x_1 + h^2 y_1 - h^2 y_0
 + h m x_1^2 - h m x_0^2 + 2 h x_1 y_0 - 2 h x_0 y_1 + 2 b h x_0 - 2 b h x_1 
- b x_0^2 + b x_1^2 + x_0^2 y_1 - x_1^2 y_0 \\
0 = h^2 ( 2 m (x_0 - x_1) + y_1 - y_0 )
 + h ( m (x_1^2 - x_0^2) + 2 (x_1 (y_0 - b) - x_0 (y_1 - b)) )
 + b (x_1^2 - x_0^2) + x_0^2 y_1 - x_1^2 y_0
$$

The quadratic equation can now be used to solve for $h$.

$$
h = \frac{-B\pm\sqrt{B^2-4 A C}}{2A} \\
A = 2 m (x_0 - x_1) + y_1 - y_0 \\
B = m (x_1^2 - x_0^2) + 2 (x_1 (y_0 - b) - x_0 (y_1 - b)) \\
C = b (x_1^2 - x_0^2) + x_0^2 y_1 - x_1^2 y_0 \\
h = \frac{-( m (x_1^2 - x_0^2) + 2 (x_1 (y_0 - b) - x_0 (y_1 - b))) \pm\sqrt{( m (x_1^2 - x_0^2) + 2 (x_1 (y_0 - b) - x_0 (y_1 - b)))^2-4 ( 2 m (x_0 - x_1) + y_1 - y_0 ) (b (x_1^2 - x_0^2) + x_0^2 y_1 - x_1^2 y_0)}}{2( 2 m (x_0 - x_1) + y_1 - y_0 )} \\
h = \frac{- m (x_1^2 - x_0^2) - 2 (x_1 (y_0 - b) - x_0 (y_1 - b)) \pm\sqrt{ (x_0 - x_1)^2 (2 m x_0 (2 b + m x_1 - 2 y_1) + 4 m x_1 (b - y_0) + 4 (b - y_0) (b - y_1) + m^2 x_0^2 + m^2 x_1^2)}}{2( 2 m (x_0 - x_1) + y_1 - y_0 )} \\
h = \frac{- m (x_1^2 - x_0^2) - 2 (x_1 (y_0 - b) - x_0 (y_1 - b)) \pm (x_0 - x_1) \sqrt{ 2 m x_0 (2 b + m x_1 - 2 y_1) + 4 m x_1 (b - y_0) + 4 (b - y_0) (b - y_1) + m^2 x_0^2 + m^2 x_1^2}}{2( 2 m (x_0 - x_1) + y_1 - y_0 )} \\
h = \frac{- m (x_1^2 - x_0^2) - 2 (x_1 (y_0 - b) - x_0 (y_1 - b)) \pm (x_0 - x_1) \sqrt{ (2 b + m ( x_0 + x_1 ) - 2 y_1)^2 - 4 (y_0 - y_1) (b + m x_1 - y_1) }}{2( 2 m (x_0 - x_1) + y_1 - y_0 )} \\
$$

Solution to sample problem.

$$
x_0 = 2 \\
y_0 = 5 \\
x_1 = 6 \\
y_1 = 53 \\
m = 2 \\
b = 1 \\
$$
$$
h = \frac{- m (x_1^2 - x_0^2) - 2 (x_1 (y_0 - b) - x_0 (y_1 - b)) \pm (x_0 - x_1) \sqrt{ (2 b + m ( x_0 + x_1 ) - 2 y_1)^2 - 4 (y_0 - y_1) (b + m x_1 - y_1) }}{2( 2 m (x_0 - x_1) + y_1 - y_0 )} \\
h = \frac{- 2 (6^2 - 2^2) - 2 (6 (5 - 1) - 2 (53 - 1)) \pm (2 - 6) \sqrt{ (2 (1) + 2 ( 2 + 6 ) - 2 (53))^2 - 4 (5 - 53) (1 + 2 (6) - 53) }}{2( 2 (2) (2 - 6) + 53 - 5 )} \\
h = \frac{96 \mp 4 \sqrt{ 64 }}{64} = \frac{3 \mp 1}{2} \\
h_0 = 1 \\
h_1 = 2 \\
$$

$$
k = \frac{y_0(x_1-h)^2 - y_1(x_0-h)^2}{(x_1-h)^2 - (x_0-h)^2} \\
k = \frac{5(6-h)^2 - 53(2-h)^2}{(6-h)^2 - (2-h)^2} \\
k_0 = \frac{5(6-h_0)^2 - 53(2-h_0)^2}{(6-h_0)^2 - (2-h_0)^2} \\
k_0 = \frac{5(6-1)^2 - 53(2-1)^2}{(6-1)^2 - (2-1)^2} = \frac{72}{24} \\
k_0 = 3\\
k_1 = \frac{5(6-h_1)^2 - 53(2-h_1)^2}{(6-h_1)^2 - (2-h_1)^2} \\
k_1 = \frac{5(6-2)^2 - 53(2-2)^2}{(6-2)^2 - (2-2)^2} = \frac{80}{16} \\
k_1 = 5
$$

$$
a = \frac{y_1 - y_0}{(x_1-h)^2 - (x_0-h)^2} \\
a = \frac{53 - 5}{(6-h)^2 - (2-h)^2} \\
a_0 = \frac{48}{(6-h_0)^2 - (2-h_0)^2} \\
a_0 = \frac{48}{(6-1)^2 - (2-1)^2} = \frac{48}{24} \\
a_0 = 2 \\
a_1 = \frac{48}{(6-h_1)^2 - (2-h_1)^2} \\
a_1 = \frac{48}{(6-2)^2 - (2-2)^2} = \frac{48}{16} \\
a_1 = 3
$$

Answer.

$$
y = a(x-h)^2+k \\
y = 2(x-1)^2+3 \\
y = 3(x-2)^2+5
$$